# Django All-Auth - Validate against linked object on account creation?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Okay, so, using Django and All-Auth handling registration (without social registration), what I'd like to do is when I take a user's name in I'd like to compare it to a second table's rows.

To cut a long story short, `user` acts as the identifier for a (real world) player, players can have many `character`s, and I want to check to make sure a `character` name isn't taken that matches the username and both register user and create the character for them matching their username if it's okay.

To be clear:

If a character with the name the user is trying to register DOES NOT exist, let the user register and create that character, too.

If a character with the name the user is trying to register DOES exist, return an error to the effect of "name already taken".

This doesn't work as a mere one-to-one extension of the user's profile because there may be many characters for each user - not merely one. There's no need for extra form fields because the necessary data should have already been entered as part of the username.

I seem to not understand validation as it happens in all-auth in a way that would make this possible, and I've read both a chunk of the source and the readthedocs page.

I'm happy to expand or answer questions on this matter. (I believe that my version of python is 2.x on my server.)

---

An extra question that I'd consider bonus to have answered:

I also want to reserve a number of character names for whatever reason as protected characters, this way people can't register accounts to match (and imposter people of merit in the target community, basically). In what way could I indicate that a name can't be used because it's a protected name and provide extra data on getting signed up with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not done anything like what you want to do, so I cannot give you the exact code, but I believe the solution is for you to define your own DefaultAccountAdapter, and try to overwrite either the `new_user` or `save_user` methods.

To write your own adapter, you need to set the following setting

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'path.to.adapters.YourAccountAdapter'
```

and then define

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class YourAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def clean_username(self, username, shallow=False):
        # -----------------------
        # do our validation first
        # -----------------------

        # character exists with username?
        if (YourModel.objects.filter(loginname__iexact=str(username))):

            # let's poke this a bit
            char = YourModel.objects.get(loginname__iexact=str(username))

            # is it a protected character name?
            if char.protected:
                raise ValidationError("Name belongs to protected character, please contact site admin to claim")
            else:
                raise ValidationError("Character with name exists, cannot use as a login name")

        # -----------------------------------------
        # if that went okay, call and return parent
        # -----------------------------------------
        return super(YourAccountAdapter, self).clean_username(username, shallow)
```

See http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html

The other alternative (or something to do as well) is to use your own signup form, where you will be able to pre-validate the username field before you accept the form. To do that, you need to add the following on your setting

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = { 'signup': 'path.to.forms.AllauthSignupForm'}
```

and then use

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
from django.core.validators import ValidationError

class AllauthSignupForm(SignupForm):

    def clean_username(self):
        # check for duplicates here and then
        if duplicate:
             raise ValidationError("Username is not allowed")

    return org
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that documentation. However, it is not made clear how to deliberately fail validation, which is the missing puzzle piece to make such a thing work, even if only in a bit of a foppish workaround form.

Comment: Just edited my response to also suggest you look into overwriting the signupform, where you could validate for duplicates even before a record is created. But to answer to your comment, you should try to raise a ValidationError or something like that from the Adapter and see what happenrs

Comment: That seems more practical. [...] 

Really, validation should happen in the model but due to wanting to interact with two models there has to be some sort of middleman talking to both. If it was one-to-one this would be a trivial, well understood problem. [...] When I work on this project again I'll try what you're suggesting. If it works, I'll comment back with any extra notes and then accept the answer so that you get credit. (Anyone else, I'm still open to hearing other ideas in the meantime.)

Comment: dkarchmer, please see the following pastebin and update your answer and I will accept it as the correct answer. I could not have done this without your assistance (sorry it took so long for me to get back to this project :D ) [...] http://pastebin.com/02y2LdYH [...] I will create the inverse relationship in RPKCharacter but that's "trivial"

Comment: Ok, see if what I wrote is understood. Just changed tour class names

Comment: Should be good enough. Be aware that protected is a property I've added to my characters, not a base property of models in Django. Accepted! :D